# Show popup based on two properties (IsFocused, IsVisible)

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, popup, datatrigger

I have popup error message box, it opens once the textbox is focused.

The issue when opening dialog window, if you click on the close button *(on close I hide the window)* the error message stays visible. I tried to add trigger to check the visibility but it didn't work. any idea?

XAML:

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="errorToolTipTemplate">
    <Grid>
        <Border BorderBrush="#EF5B7C" BorderThickness="1" Background="#EF5B7C" Opacity="0.4" IsHitTestVisible="False" x:Name="errorBorder" />
        <AdornedElementPlaceholder x:Name="placeholder" />
        <Popup x:Name="popup" AllowsTransparency="True"
               PopupAnimation="Fade"
               Placement="Right"
               VerticalOffset="-3"
               PlacementTarget="{Binding ElementName=errorBorder}"
               IsOpen="{Binding ElementName=placeholder, Path=AdornedElement.IsFocused, Mode=OneWay}">
            <Popup.Style>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type Popup}">
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=errorBorder, Path=IsVisible, Mode=OneWay}" Value="False">
                            <Setter Property="IsOpen" Value="False" />
                        </DataTrigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </Popup.Style>
            <DockPanel>
                <Polygon VerticalAlignment="Center"
                         Points="0,5 5,0 5,10"
                         Fill="#EF5B7C"
                         Stretch="Fill" />
                <Border Background="White" BorderBrush="#EF5B7C" BorderThickness="1" CornerRadius="4" Padding="2">
                    <DockPanel>
                        <Image Height="20" Width="20" VerticalAlignment="Center" Source="Images/C04_32.png" />
                        <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                   VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                   Foreground="{StaticResource errorBrush}"
                                   FontWeight="Bold" Margin="2,0,0,0"
                                   Text="{Binding ElementName=placeholder, Path=AdornedElement.ToolTip, Mode=OneWay}" />
                    </DockPanel>
                </Border>
            </DockPanel>
        </Popup>
    </Grid>
</ControlTemplate>

<!--Textbox style-->
<Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
    <Setter Property="Validation.ErrorTemplate" Value="{DynamicResource errorToolTipTemplate}" />
</Style>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed this by adding `triggers` for the `ControlTemplate`.
I have add trigger with `SourceTarget` as the `adorner`, and `TargetName` as the popup, and changed the `IsOpen` property according to the other control visibility.

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="errorToolTipTemplate">
    <Grid>
        <Border BorderBrush="#EF5B7C" BorderThickness="1" Background="#EF5B7C" Opacity="0.4" IsHitTestVisible="False" x:Name="errorBorder" />
        <AdornedElementPlaceholder x:Name="placeholder" />
        <Popup x:Name="popup" AllowsTransparency="True"
               PopupAnimation="Fade"
               Placement="Right"
               VerticalOffset="-3"
               PlacementTarget="{Binding ElementName=errorBorder}"
               IsOpen="{Binding ElementName=placeholder, Path=AdornedElement.IsFocused, Mode=OneWay}">
            <DockPanel>
                <Polygon VerticalAlignment="Center"
                         Points="0,5 5,0 5,10"
                         Fill="#EF5B7C"
                         Stretch="Fill" />
                <Border Background="White" BorderBrush="#EF5B7C" BorderThickness="1" CornerRadius="4" Padding="2">
                    <DockPanel>
                        <Image Height="20" Width="20" VerticalAlignment="Center" Source="Images/C04_32.png" />
                        <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                   VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                   Foreground="{StaticResource errorBrush}"
                                   FontWeight="Bold" Margin="2,0,0,0"
                                   Text="{Binding ElementName=placeholder, Path=AdornedElement.ToolTip, Mode=OneWay}" />
                    </DockPanel>
                </Border>
            </DockPanel>
        </Popup>
    </Grid>
    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
        <Trigger SourceName="placeholder" Property="IsVisible" Value="False">
            <Setter TargetName="popup" Property="IsOpen" Value="False" />
        </Trigger>
    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
</ControlTemplate>
```